# Single field inequality works in dev and fails in production

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

The following query works in Dev datastore on local machine and fails in production.

```
List<ChildDTO> res = OfyService.ofy()
            .load()
            .type(classOfChild)
            .ancestor(parentKey)
            .filter("date >=", fromDateOnly)
            .filter("date <=", toDateOnly)
            .list();
```

As far as I know, a single field with multiple inequalities is supported.

Is there some configuration on the index which can indicate that it should include ancestor?

According to the exception description, the following index configuration is required. Is it possible to achieve this with Objectify annotations instead of the xml configuration?

```
<datastore-index kind="ChildDTO" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="date" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Comment: No, you cannot specify multiproperty indexes with Objectify annotations. You need the XML (or yaml, if that's your preferred flavor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may be misleading in this case is that the query *appears* to be a single property query, which would be using a simple, single-property index, achievable using objectify annotations.

But this is not the case: this is an ancestor query, the presence of an ancestor counts as the second property, which is why a composite index is needed. And AFAIK composite indexes can't be handled by objectify annotations.

The reason for which this is working in the local development environment is that the developer server automatically updates the indexes file with the missing composite index. But that needs to be done explicitly done for the apps running on GAE.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll do it via XML then. Does this mean I have to remove the index objectify annotations on the entity and use only the XML to specify all index properties on this kind? And then also resave the instances?

Comment: I'm not an objectify user, so I'm not entire sure about removal of the index annotations. If removing them translates to marking the respective properties as unindexed that would probably not work - you still need them indexed if they're gonna be used in a composite index. You shouldn't need to re-write the entities if you're uploading a new composite index - GAE will automatically index existing properties in this case. Re-writing is only necessary after switching a property from unindexed to indexed while entities already exist.

Comment: Thanks. Yes.. now I remember reading somewhere that multi field index would be built gradually by GAE without resave.